# eBay Trading API addFixedPriceItem Call Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ebay-api

I'm trying to make a call to addFixedPriceItem in NodeJS. I'm using the NodeJS eBay API. My code is the following:

```
var ebay = require('ebay-api');
ebay.ebayApiPostXmlRequest({
    serviceName: 'Trading',
    opType: 'AddFixedPriceItem',
    devName: myDevId,
    cert: myCertId,
    appName: myAppId,
    sandbox: true,
    title: title,
    params: {
        'authToken': myClientAuthToken,
        version: EBAY_API_VERSION,
        Item: {
            Country: 'EBAY-US', 
            Currency: 'USD',
            Description: description,
            ListingType: 'FixedPriceItem',
            PictureDetails: picturesArray,
            Quantity: '5',
            StartPrice: price
        },
    }
}, function (error, results) {
    if (error) {
        console.dir(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.dir(results);
});
```

Ultimately, I cannot seem to get it to call. It's not a verification issue or anything, console is stating that No Item.Country exists, and No Item.Currency exists, although I have specifically placed these in my parameters. Any clue why this would occur?

If not, how could I make a call to this in nodeJS without this API? I appreciate any help! :)

Comment: [ebay official sdk](https://go.developer.ebay.com/ebay-sdks) does not seem to support nodejs yet.

Comment: this is true, however an API has been made and is available on GitHub here: github.com/benbuckman/nodejs-ebay-api/ Sorry, forgot to provide a link previously!

Comment: what I meant to say was official sdks are likely more robust.

Comment: you're right, and I probably should use the XML API. Unfortunately, I'm awful at making SOAP requests :(  - I used NodeJS simply because I'm so used to it, but I seriously think it's an issue with that API now.

Comment: if it is not big codebase, you may consider python/net/java instead of writing a js client for ebay

Comment: I guess I could write a Java client to do the trading API work for me and use socket.io to communicate with the website (this is all going to be local).. wish it could be NodeJS though, it'd make it a lot easier on my end

Answer (score 0):

Your country code is wrong. It should be `'US'` or one of the other [CountryCodeType](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/types/CountryCodeType.html)'s.

Comment: I tried this as well, and unfortunately it does not work, either :(

Comment: Do you still get the No Item.Country and No Item.Currency exists error?